# Excel file with openxml with multiple sheets in single workbook

Tags: c#, openxml, spreadsheetml

I am trying to insert data to multiple sheets. For my excel, I have two sheets which are "charts" and "ChartData". I'm able to update the data in sheet2, chartdata sheet, but I'm unable to insert data to sheet1. Here is code which I have tried to insert data into excel sheets. Here data is coming from database.

```
           double ticks = DateTime.Now.Ticks;
         // MarketAnalysis ms = new MarketAnalysis();
         //ms.Marketanalysis();

        File.Copy(Srcpath, @"E:\Works\OpenXML\DownloadTemplates\ExcelGenerated" + ticks + ".xlsx", true);
         using (SpreadsheetDocument myworkbok = SpreadsheetDocument.Open(@"E:\Works\OpenXML\DownloadTemplates\ExcelGenerated" + ticks + ".xlsx", true))
         {
             //Acess the main workbook which contain all the references

            WorkbookPart workbookpart = myworkbok.WorkbookPart;
             //Get sheet by name
             Sheet sheet = workbookpart.Workbook.Descendants<Sheet>().Where(s => s.Name == "ChartData").FirstOrDefault();

            //Worksheet Part by ID
             WorksheetPart worksheetpart = workbookpart.GetPartById(sheet.Id) as WorksheetPart;

            //Sheet data contains all the data
             SheetData sheetdata = worksheetpart.Worksheet.GetFirstChild<SheetData>();
             DataSet ds = db.Chart1Data();

              for (int i = 0; i < ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count; i++)
             {
                 //  if (ds.Tables[0].Rows !=DBNull)
                 //{

                string Rowlabel = ds.Tables[0].Rows[i][0].ToString();
                 // float? FY13Actuval = Convert.ToInt32(ds.Tables[0].Rows[i][1]);

                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(ds.Tables[0].Rows[i][1].ToString()))
                 {
                     // string s = ds.Tables[0].Rows[i][1].ToString();
                     //FY13Actuval=float.Parse(ds.Tables[0].Rows[i][1].ToString());

                    FY13Actuval = Convert.ToDouble(ds.Tables[0].Rows[i][1].ToString());
                 }
                 else
                 {

                    FY13Actuval = null;
                 }

                double? Budget = Convert.ToDouble(ds.Tables[0].Rows[i][2].ToString());
                 double? Actuval = Convert.ToDouble(ds.Tables[0].Rows[i][3].ToString());
                 Row contentrow = CreateContentRow(index, Product, Actual, Budget, Forecast);

                index++;
                 sheetdata.AppendChild(contentrow);

                // }
             }
 .......Same code for the other 3 charts
 Sheet sheet1 = workbookpart.Workbook.Descendants<Sheet>().Where(s => s.Name == "Charts").FirstOrDefault();

            WorksheetPart worksheetpart1 = workbookpart.GetPartById(sheet1.Id) as WorksheetPart;

            //Sheet data contains all the data
             SheetData sheetdata1 = worksheetpart1.Worksheet.GetFirstChild<SheetData>();

            DataSet dsTbl = db.Table();
             int SCMTblIndex=5;
             for (int i = 0; i < dsTbl.Tables[0].Rows.Count; i++)
             {
                 Row tblRow = CreateScorecardMetricTblRow(SCMTblIndex, dsTbl.Tables[0].Rows[i][0].ToString(),
                                                                    dsTbl.Tables[0].Rows[i][1].ToString(),
                                                                    dsTbl.Tables[0].Rows[i][2].ToString());
                 SCMTblIndex++;
                 sheetdata1.AppendChild(tblRow);
             }

                myworkbok.WorkbookPart.Workbook.Save();
         }
```

and the Methods to create the cells:

```
public static string[] headerColumns = new string[]{ "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "I", "J" };
public static string[] header = new string[] { "D", "E", "F" };

private static Row CreateContentRow(int index, string Product, double? Actual, double? Budget, double? Forecast)
     {

        //Create New ROw
         Row r = new Row();
         r.RowIndex = (UInt32)index;


        //Begin colums
         Cell c0 = new Cell();
         c0.CellReference = headerColumns[0] + index;
         CellValue v0 = new CellValue();
         v0.Text = Product;
         c0.AppendChild(v0);
         r.AppendChild(c0);

        Cell c1 = new Cell();
         c1.CellReference = headerColumns[1] + index;
         CellValue v1 = new CellValue();
         v1.Text = Actual.ToString();
         c1.AppendChild(v1);
         r.AppendChild(c1);

        Cell c2 = new Cell();
         c2.CellReference = headerColumns[2] + index;
         CellValue v2 = new CellValue();
         v2.Text = Budget.ToString();
         c2.AppendChild(v2);
         r.AppendChild(c2);

        Cell c3 = new Cell();
         c3.CellReference = headerColumns[3] + index;
         CellValue v3 = new CellValue();
         v3.Text = Forecast.ToString();
         c3.AppendChild(v3);
         r.AppendChild(c3);


        return r;


    }
public static Row CreateScorecardMetricTblRow(int index, string Act_Data, string Bud_Data, string VarPr_Data)
     {
         Row r = new Row();
         r.RowIndex = (UInt32)index;
         //Begin Colums

        Cell c0 = new Cell();
         c0.CellReference = header[0] + index;
         CellValue v0 = new CellValue();
         v0.Text = Act_Data;
         c0.AppendChild(v0);
         r.AppendChild(c0);

        Cell c1 = new Cell();
         c1.CellReference = header[1] + index;
         CellValue v1 = new CellValue();
         v1.Text = Bud_Data;
         c1.AppendChild(v1);
         r.AppendChild(c1);

        Cell c2 = new Cell();
         c2.CellReference = header[2] + index;
         CellValue v2 = new CellValue();
         v2.Text = VarPr_Data;
         c2.AppendChild(v2);
         r.AppendChild(c2);
          return r;
     }
```

Comment: Write these code instead of declaring Sheet sheet=Workbookpart.workbook.....etc , write these                   var sheet = workbookpart.Workbook.Descendants<Sheet>().Where(s => s.Name.Value.Contains("Sheet"));                foreach (var sheetname in sheet)
            {
                if (sheetname.Name == "Sheet1")
                {
                       }

Answer (score 3, accepted):

for multiple sheets to updated just

```
// Open the document for editing.
using (SpreadsheetDocument spreadSheet = SpreadsheetDocument.Open(docName, true)) 
{

   // Insert code here.

}
```

create a two classes for two sheets which you need to update sheet cell values.For each class constructor pass the **SpreadsheetDocument** object and implement [insert text into a cell in a spreadsheet document](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/cc861607.aspx).Just avoid the code for insertion of new sheet and try the insertion of the cell code only.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this method.....it may be helpful..

```
    private static Cell InsertCellInWorksheet(string columnName, int rowIndex, WorksheetPart worksheetPart)
    {
        Worksheet worksheet = worksheetPart.Worksheet;
        SheetData sheetData = worksheet.GetFirstChild<SheetData>();
        string cellReference = columnName + rowIndex;

        Alignment alignment1 = new Alignment() { WrapText = true };
        
        // If the worksheet does not contain a row with the specified row index, insert one.
        Row row;
        row = new Row() { RowIndex = 3, StyleIndex = 1 };
        if (sheetData.Elements<Row>().Where(r => r.RowIndex == rowIndex).Count() != 0)
        {
            row = sheetData.Elements<Row>().Where(r => r.RowIndex == rowIndex).First();
        }
        else
        {
            row = new Row() { RowIndex = Convert.ToUInt32(rowIndex) };
            sheetData.Append(row);
        }

        // If there is not a cell with the specified column name, insert one.  
        if (row.Elements<Cell>().Where(c => c.CellReference.Value == columnName + rowIndex).Count() > 0)
        {
            Row row2;
            row2 = new Row() { RowIndex = 3, StyleIndex = 1 };
            Cell rCell = null;
            foreach (Cell celld in row.Elements<Cell>())
            {
                if (string.Compare(celld.CellReference.Value, "A3", true) > 0)
                {
                    rCell = celld;
                    break;
                }
            }

            // Add the cell to the cell table at A1.
            Cell newCell = new Cell() { CellReference = "C3" };
            //Cell newCell1 = new Cell() { CellReference = "D3" };
            row.InsertBefore(newCell, rCell);
            //row.InsertBefore(newCell1, rCell);

            // Set the cell value to be a numeric value of 100.
            newCell.CellValue = new CellValue("#GUIDeXactLCMS#");
            //newCell1.CellValue = new CellValue("EN");
            newCell.DataType = new EnumValue<CellValues>(CellValues.Number);

            return row.Elements<Cell>().Where(c => c.CellReference.Value == cellReference).First();
        }
        else
        {
            // Cells must be in sequential order according to CellReference. Determine where to insert the new cell.
            Cell refCell = null;
            foreach (Cell cell in row.Elements<Cell>())
            {
                if (string.Compare(cell.CellReference.Value, cellReference, true) > 0)
                {
                    //string val = cell.CellReference.Value;
                    refCell = cell;
                    break;
                }
            }

            Cell newCell = new Cell() { CellReference = cellReference };
            row.InsertBefore(newCell, refCell);

            
            return newCell;
            
            
        }
        worksheet.Save();
    }
```